# using powershell inside batch file to add floating numbers from text file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, ffprobe

i have a text file logging timestamps from ffprobe on video durations of some video files,  which that text file looks like this:

```
14.068700
5.043011
84.071967
5.043011
104.058600
5.043011
134.055234
5.056000 ....
```

I am trying to add these up,  since batch files do not allow for floating numbers i chose to use powershell.   here is my following code:

```
set total=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in (timestamps.txt) do (
    set item=%%x    
    echo !item!
    for /f  "delims=." %%i in ('powershell %total% + %item%') DO SET total=%%i      
    echo %total%    
)
```

but again it seems cause it is a floating number i am unable to do something like

```
 SET /a total=%total% + %total%
```

so that i can not add that as a variable in this line:

```
 powershell %total% + %item%
```

I have tried every combo i can think of with no luck, lots of searches and nothing comes back.

any idea how to do this or is there a better way to add up all these in pure batch ?

Comment: You could achieve this with just PowerShell: `Get-Content -Path "timestamps.txt" | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum`

Comment: thanks but i need to keep in batch for now.  Its ok if it is not in a loop too, is that code something i could use in a batch file?

Comment: Probably! It's worth a shot.

Comment: You can fix your code if you use `for /f %%i in ('powershell !total! + !item!') DO SET total=%%i` and move the final `echo %total%` _outside_ of the loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a pure `Powershell` solution would have been much simpler, but seeing as you require `batch-file` with `powershell`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set nums=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("timestamps.txt") do set nums=!nums!%%x+
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('powershell %nums:~0,-1%') do set "total=%%i"
echo Total: %total%
```

We just append all the numbers with the operator `+` to a variable, then pass that variable to `powershell` and get the result.
Note! `delayedexpansion` is needed because we are setting

or by utilizing `powershell` to do all the work and simply assign the result to the variable:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"powershell -command (Get-Content -Path "timestamps.txt" ^| Measure-Object -Sum^).Sum"') do set "total=%%i"
echo Total: %total%
```

Comment: thanks even though i added my answer below, yours is def faster.  thank you

Answer (score 0):

so this is what i came up with,  not as elegant as it possibly can be BUT it is working.  Wish it was a bit quicker  but PowerShell slows things down a bit but definitely worth it!

its crazy to think when doing dos they never thought of using floating  numbers, lol

anyways here is code:

```
set seconds=0
set item=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%t in (%filename%_copy_two%fileextension%) do (
        set item=%%t
        for /f %%i in ('powershell !item!+!seconds!') do (set seconds=%%i) 
    )
    
for /f %%i in ('powershell -NoP "[Math]::Round(!seconds!/ 60,2)"')  do (set minutes=%%i) 

set HH=00
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%r in ('echo %minutes%') do set min=%%r
for /f "tokens=2 delims=." %%p in ('echo %minutes%') do set sec=%%p

IF %sec% GTR 60 (
    set /a newSec=!sec!-60
    if !newSec! lss 10 set newSec=0!newSec!
    set /a newMin=1 + !min!
    if !newMin! lss 10 set newMin=0!newMin!
    
) else (
    set /a newMin=!min!
    set /a newSec=!sec!
)

IF %newMin% LSS 60 (
    if !newMin! lss 10 set newMin=0!newMin!
    set MM=!newMin!
    if !newSec! lss 10 set newSec=0!newSec!
    set SS=!newSec!
    GOTO playlistTotal  
)

IF %newMin% GEQ 60 IF %newMin% LSS 120 (
    set /a MM=!newMin!-60
    if !MM! lss 10 set MM=0!MM!
    set /a HH=01
    set SS=!newSec!
    GOTO playlistTotal  
)

IF %newMin% GEQ 120 IF %newMin% LSS 180 (
    set /a MM=!newMin!-120
    if !MM! lss 10 set MM=0!MM! 
    set /a HH=02
    set SS=!newSec!
    GOTO playlistTotal
) 

IF %newMin% GEQ 120 IF %newMin% LSS 240 (
    set /a MM=!newMin!-180
    if !MM! lss 10 set MM=0!MM!
    set /a HH=03    
    set SS=!newSec!
    GOTO playlistTotal
) 

IF !newMin! EQU 240 (
    set /a MM=!newMin!-240
    if !MM! lss 10 set MM=0!MM!
    set /a HH=04    
    set SS=!newSec! 
    GOTO playlistTotal  
) 

IF %newMin% Gtr 240 (
    ECHO  We do not suggest a single playlist over 4 hours.
    echo  Please Go back edit your list to be shorter.
    ECHO  And just append to it
    del %filename%_copy%fileextension%
    del %filename%_copy_two%fileextension%
    GOTO editPlaylist
)


:playlistTotal
del %filename%_copy%fileextension%
del %filename%_copy_two%fileextension% 
echo.
Echo Playlist a total duration of = !HH!:!MM!:!SS!
echo.

IF !newMin! EQU 240 (
    set /a MM=!newMin!-240
    if !MM! lss 10 set MM=0!MM!
    set /a HH=04    
    set SS=!newSec! 
    GOTO playlistTotal  
) 

IF %newMin% Gtr 240 (
    ECHO  We do not suggest a single playlist over 4 hours.
    echo  Please Go back edit your list to be shorter.
    ECHO  And just append to it
    del %filename%_copy%fileextension%
    del %filename%_copy_two%fileextension%
    GOTO editPlaylist
)


:playlistTotal
del %filename%_copy%fileextension%
del %filename%_copy_two%fileextension% 
echo.
Echo Playlist has a total duration of= !HH!:!MM!:!SS!
echo.
```

I hope this helps someone out! kind of stinks i cant ask a question for 6 months for this question considering there is NOT solution that I can find that met me OP

And once again I posted my solution after a question which I try to do every time, have a great day!

EDIT:  thanks to @Gerhard

I have changed to this, but leaving  the code here in case someone needs for a similar issue in a different way.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('"powershell -command (Get-Content -Path "%filename%_copy_two%fileextension%" ^| Measure-Object -Sum^).Sum"') do set "seconds=%%i"
for /f %%i in ('powershell -NoP "[Math]::Round(!seconds!/ 60,2)"')  do (set minutes=%%i)
```

Then keeping the same as is till someone posts a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in a very simple and pure Batch file that run *much* faster than any PS:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set /A factor=1000000, total=0
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%a in (timestamps.txt) do set /A total+=%%a*factor+1%%b-factor

echo %total:~0,-6%.%total:~-6%
```

Of course, this solution is so simple because it assumes that all input numbers have 6 decimals! If this is not the case, then the code should be modified accordingly...

Comment: Mmmm... It worked?